# How do I batch results using DynamoDBContext

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB .NET object persistence model to scan a table with conditions as below.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(string attribute1Value, string attribute2Value
{
    IEnumerable<Product> products = null;
    try
    {
        RegionEndpoint region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-1");
        AmazonDynamoDB client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(account.AwsAccessKey, account.AwsSecretKey, region);

        DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(client);
        products = context.Scan<Product>(
            new ScanCondition("attribute1", ScanOperator.Equal, attribute1Value),
            new ScanCondition("attribute2", ScanOperator.Equal, attribute2Value));

    }
    catch (AmazonServiceException ase)
    {
        log.Error("Amazon Service Exception, Message: " + ase.Message + ", request id: " + ase.RequestId);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Error("Exception: " + e.Message);
    }
    return products;
}
```

How do I handle output when it exceeds 1 MB limit set by DynamoDB when I am using DynamoDBContext?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hit the 1MB limit, DynamoDB will return multiple pages of items. The DynamoDBContext.Scan operation will automatically page your result set (lazy-loading). So, from your viewpoint, nothing extra needs to be done, simply enumerate over the IEnumerable object and all matching items will be returned.

Comment: Pavel, Thanks a lot. I spent several hours trying to figure this out. Hopefully there is documentation that I overlooked.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetORMDynamoDBContext.html